# A text box appears when I load the page even though I have set its "style:display" to none

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" name="otherPONumber" id="otherPONumber" maxlength="25" style="display: none;">


<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleField(val) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('otherPONumber');
        if(obj != undefined && txt != undefined) {
        (val == 'Other')? obj.style.display = 'block' : obj.style.display = 'none';

    }
}

</script>
```

Inspite of this, the text box appears when the page loads.

Comment: `!= undefined` is bad. Always use `!== undefined` (and `=== undefined` in the negated case)

Comment: please provide more details like the HTML page, also use code tag when you are adding code...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did that. But the text box still appears when the page first loads.

Answer (score 1):

```
(val == 'Other')? obj.style.display = 'block' : obj.style.display = 'none';
```

This abuse of the ternary operator is torrible. Replace it with the following:

```
obj.style.display = (val == 'Other') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

If the element is displayed right after loading, use Firefox (or a similar tool) to check if there's some CSS rule overriding your inline style.